# Why is my program not being killed by a system call to pkill from another program?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

I am trying to write an integration test that exercises the interaction between two separate programs. Program A is a utility program that generates data for use by Program B, so I am starting Program A with a call to

```
system("ProgramA params");
```

This part works, so then Program B will run, and later on, after the data analysis is finished, I want to kill off Program A, so I do

```
system("pkill -2 ProgramA");
```

This call returns 0, and so the integration test ends, but when I run

```
pgrep ProgramA
```

from the terminal, it shows a PID, indicating that the process is still running.

Furthermore, if I run Program A from the command line, the signalHandler does execute when I Ctrl-C to send SIGINT, indicating that the signalHandler is catching the signals at least sometimes.

Program A is multithreaded, using pthread library, where the main thread is using

```
signal(SIGINT, *signalHandler)
```

to catch the interrupts, and all child processes are blocking all signals.

And yes, I run pgrep before the integration test to ensure there are no stray processes running Program A.

What am I missing?

Comment: "What am I missing?" The notion of "zombie process" perhaps. It isn't quite clear which program does what, so it's a bit hard to tell.

Comment: @n.m. Which part is confusing? The integration test is making all system calls to start and stop Program A. Program B is simply another program (that is running correctly) during the integration test.

Comment: `system` normally waits until the program being ran finishes, so I can only guess what is really meant by "start and stop".